# My width is bigger than my screen, but body and html are set to 0 padding and margin and 100% width

Tags: html, css, width, scrollbar, padding

After removing bootstrap I've run into this issue with the width of my page being larger than the screen, and having a horizontal scroll bar as a result. I thought setting body, html to 0 padding and margin as well as 100% width would be okay but the issue persists..

SOLUTION EDIT: I had images that were wider than the view, so I needed to set `box-sizing: border-box` to contain the images in the parent. Then I inherited this for all elements. So now the top of my CSS is:

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

html:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<div class="main">
    <div class="content">
        <div id="welcome" class="page">
            <h1>asasd</h1>
            <p>
                test3
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="asdasd" class="page" data-original="/Images/asdh.jpg">
            <h1>asdasd</h1>
            <p>
                test2
            </p>
            <div class="vfd"></div>
            <div class="measurment"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="test2" class="page" data-original="/Images/test.jpg">
            <h1></h1>
            <p>test
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: stretch;
    padding: 0;
    height: 300vh;
}

.page {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-left: 25%;
    padding-right: 25%;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Are your images what is making your screen width overflow? You can always use box-sizing to help with clearing margins and padding: https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Comment: yup! this worked thanks, learned something new : )

I'll mark as answer in 2 mins

Comment: Thanks a lot, in my case it was due to a video scroll <section> exceeding the width limit than body but it was only catchable when inspecting the element :- )

Answer (score 8):

Use `box-sizing: border-box;` so your padding are included into width. Otherwise, your real width is 100% + 25% + 25% = 150%.

[image]

> CSS3 box-sizing Property
>
> **content-box**    Default. The width and height properties (and min/max properties) includes only the content. Border, padding, or margin are not included
>
> **border-box** The width and height properties (and min/max properties) includes content, padding and border, but not the margin

```css
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: stretch;
    padding: 0;
    height: 300vh;
}

.page {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-left: 25%;
    padding-right: 25%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="content">
        <div id="welcome" class="page">
            <h1>asasd</h1>
            <p>
                test3
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="asdasd" class="page" data-original="/Images/asdh.jpg">
            <h1>asdasd</h1>
            <p>
                test2
            </p>
            <div class="vfd"></div>
            <div class="measurment"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="test2" class="page" data-original="/Images/test.jpg">
            <h1></h1>
            <p>test
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the solution but padding wasn't my issue. Images were. Thanks though!

Comment: @J.Doe in fact, `box-sizing: border-box` solved both issues, padding and img, good luck =D

Comment: For a global default:
`body {box-sizing: border-box;}`
and
`body * {box-sizing: border-box;}`

Comment: this comment worked, not the answer , lol

Answer (score 0):

Just replace this part in your CSS and the horizontal scroll will be gone:

```
.content {
       display:inline-block;
      /*display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: stretch;*/
      padding: 0;
      height: 300vh;
 }
```

But I don't really understand what you are trying to accomplish with those CSS codes.